Jetpack Compose Identify The Focused Item In Talkback
Trying to solve an accessibility bug.
Is there a way to extract what is the item on the screen that the blue Talkback box surrounds?
Here is a composable function for illustration, for this case I'd be happy to Log the text parameter of this item, so I can recognize it:
@Composable
fun TalkbackFocusDemo() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        TalkbackFocusableItem("Item 1")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
        TalkbackFocusableItem("Item 2")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
        TalkbackFocusableItem("Item 3")
    }
}

@Composable
fun TalkbackFocusableItem(text: String) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(8.dp)
            .border(1.dp, Color.Gray)
            .padding(16.dp)
            .semantics {
                contentDescription = "Talkback focusable item: $text"
            }
    ) {
        Text(text)
    }
}


Thanks!
